# angular routes in separate modules pointing to same component

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-routing, angular-module

I'm refactoring a single-module angular app into multiple feature modules.

Besides better code, my focus is on implementing lazy-loading of feature modules.

I have a set of components to organize into two feature modules, each with their own routes.

For the general case, I do know how to do this.

However, I have my hands on a more peculiar case, because both feature modules would have a certain route pointing to the same `XComponent` as follows

`{path: /a-module/x, component: XComponent}`

`{path: /b-module/x, component: XComponent}`

**Question**

I would like to know if the following solution is feasible, before beginning the refactoring.

1. define `AModule` and its routes, and declare its components
2. define `BModule` and its routes, and declare its components
3. define `CModule`
4. declare and export `XComponent` from `CModule`
5. import `CModule` in `AModule` and `BModule`
6. add `{path: /a-module/x, component: XComponent}` to `AModule`'s routes
7. add `{path: /b-module/x, component: XComponent}` to `BModule`'s routes
8. lazy-load `AModule` with `loadChildren: 'app/a/a.module#AModule'`
9. lazy-load `BModule` with `loadChildren: 'app/b/b.module#BModule'`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Sure. CModule takes the role of a Module which most developer call SharedModule.

AModule and BModule will get their own copy of the CModule.

Comment: Hi, what worries me is the fact that the modules using CModule are lazy-loaded, so I wonder if the app would then break if users first visit rotues of AModule and then routes if BModule.

Comment: AModule doesn't even know that BModule also uses CModule

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules for an example of a SharedModule

Answer (score 0):

You can have them in both modules and it might still be working, you can add a preloading strategy to your `RouterModule.forRoot()` and both of the routes will be available.

I do suggest you pull this route to a different feature module, that is loaded before all other modules that use this route. This way there won't be an issue if it's going to work or not.